# $\left((x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n) > \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\rightarrow (\exists i\in P\,.\,x_i>i)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove the following statement for a collection of natural numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n$ and the set $P =\{1, 2, . . . , n\} $.
>
> $$\left((x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n) > \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\rightarrow (\exists i\in P\,.\,x_i>i)$$

How would one prove this questions? Is there a way to phrase this question into word form? I am not sure what this question even mean.

Comment: Maybe by contraposition? Assume instead that $$\forall i \in \mathcal I, x_i\le i$$

Comment: Hint: Prove the contrapositive

Comment: I don't really get what the question is asking me, i assume the contraposition, how do i get from there to (x1+x2+..xn) < (n(n=1))/2

Answer (score 1):

The condition on the left can be re-written as 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-i)>0\implies \exists i\text{ such that }x_i>i.$$
So now suppose that $\forall i$ we had that $x_i\leq i$ then we would get that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-i)\leq 0$$ which contradicts our hypothesis and so the proof is done.

Comment: how did you rephrase the left side to (xi - i)?

Comment: Do you know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}?$